# REP-57054: 'In Process Job Terminated' error while executing oracle reports

Tags: oraclereports

When i am executing oracle reports i got above mentioned error.

I m using query with three formula columns and generating XML for RTF.

All formula columns compiled successfully. how to resolve this issue?

[Error While Executing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLPrN.png)

Answer (score 1):

Workaround of setting cacheSize to 50 in `$INST_TOP/ora/10.1.2/reports/conf/rwbuilder.conf`  while waiting for this fix.

When cacheSize is 0 in server conf file, `Cache.manage()` removes output files in cache directory after a request is successfully finished."

But a non-zero value disables the cache clean up functionality.

Check more details Oracle Doc ID 1237834.1

Answer (score 0):

1. close most of the windows as there may be any memory issue
2. then save the report as .jsp file format and try to run and generate to pdf
3. again save the .jsp report in .rdf file format.

in this way, I solved my issue.